# how to remove after text after spacial character with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

this is my html code:

```js
jQuery('.variation').ready(function(){
  var the_string = jQuery('p').text();
  var removed = the_string.split('*', 1);
  jQuery('p').text(removed);
});
```

```css
td{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="page-id-9">
<table class="woocommerce">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#1</td>
        <td class="tdclass"><span class="other_item">wallet</span></td>
        <td class="tdclass">$45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Time of match 33india * 45</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Place of match 21dl * 123</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to remove text after like bellow (2 methods),this is my text:

Time of match 33india * 45

and i want to convert to :

Time of match

---

and also i want to convert another:

Time of match 33india * 45

to :

45

Comment: I don't understand the expected result.

Comment: @ djcaesar9114 update question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `text()` creates one big string from all elements in the collection.

You need to loop over each specific element to use `text()`. A simple way is use [`text(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) which will loop over all instances for you

Give all the `<p>` you need to modify a class name in order to filter them from ones that don't need updating

Something like:

```js
jQuery('p.time, p.place').text(function(_, curr) {  
  return  curr.split('*').pop().trim();      
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
table{width:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="page-id-9">
  <table class="woocommerce">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#1</td>
        <td class="tdclass"><span class="other_item">wallet</span></td>
        <td class="tdclass">$45</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p>Category 1</p>
            </dd>
            <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p class="time">Time of match 33india * 45</p>
            </dd>
            <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
            </dd>
          </dl>
          <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
          <dl class="variation">
            <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p>Category 1</p>
            </dd>
            <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p class="place">Place of match 21dl * 123</p>
            </dd>
            <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
            <dd class="variation-">
              <p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p>
            </dd>
          </dl>
          <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: very thanks. this is work well. but for my first request, jQuery has any solution? (Time of match 33india * 45 ---- > Time of match)

Comment: Ok simpler... `$('p.time').text("Time of match')` and only use the function approach for the other class

Comment: thanks. can you show me an example? I'm confused :)

Comment: Look at the classes I added to those specific `<p>` ... change the version in my answer to just `jQuery('p.place').text(function(_, curr) {...` and then use the one in above comment for `p.time`

Comment: Create a demo and show me then. Can do it easily in jsfiddle.net, or jsbin. Just saying "not work" tells me very little of value

Comment: i have so many of (Time of match 33india * 45) text with the template. but different text. such as (book of libe 21jorj * 15) or (vid of bill 41jhrj * 11). i want to trim before number is starting.look at : (vid of bill 41jhrj * 11) --> (vid of bill)

Comment: Where and how is that text generated? Sounds like it would be simpler to change it at the source. Also none of that was shown in the sample html

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the source.in woocommerce when using TMExtra filed and data was showing with this template in order page.

Comment: the template is : (filed name price currency * quantity) and i want to show only (filed name)

Comment: Midnight where I am...won't be able to help more for about 8 hours